# Error 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' when Iterating through Dictionary and Removing dictionary entry

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, foreach

I am Iterating through a Dictionary and I want to trying to remove certain un required keys from the Dictionary .

My code is as follows

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> stackOfItems in ItemStack)
            {
                string Name = stackOfItems .Key;
                string Price= stackOfItems .Value;

                if (listOfSelectedOldItems.Contains(Name))
                {
                    ItemStack.Remove(Name);
                }

            }
```

All I am trying to do is removing a Dictionary entry (key and value) if a certain Key is in a List . The full error :- System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' in dictionary

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Nope , thats something else

Comment: It's the same thing: you're iterating over `ItemStack`, while also modifying it. That is not allowed.

Comment: You can't remove an item from a collection you are actually using its iterator

Comment: `foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> stackOfItems in ItemStack.ToList()) ...` - now loop over dictionary's *copy*

Comment: Why not do something like `foreach (var item in listOfSelectedOldItems) { ItemStack.Remove(item); }`?

Comment: @canton7 indeed ! My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `foreach` uses an enumerator and it becomes invalid when you remove items.

You can build a list of items to remove and do the actual removal in a second step.

```
var keysToRemove = new List<string>();
foreach (var stackOfItems in ItemStack)
{
    string Name = stackOfItems.Key;
    string Price= stackOfItems.Value;

    if (listOfSelectedOldItems.Contains(Name))
    {
        keysToRemove.Add(Name);
    }
}

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
{
    ItemStack.Remove(key);
}
```

**Update**

As canton7 said, you can simply just try to remove all items that are in `listOfSelectedOldItems`.

```
foreach (var key in listOfSelectedOldItems)
{
    ItemStack.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: As @canton7 already notices under the question, `listOfSelectedOldItems` is ... a list of keys to remove.

Comment: Yeah, the work to test each of the `ItemStack` entries against `listOfSelectedOldItems` is, as far as I can see, entirely pointless (unless `listOfSelctedOldItems` is huge,`ItemStack` is tiny, and `listOfSelectedOldItems.Contains` is O(1), which I see no indication of)

Comment: `listOfSelectedOldItems` might contain all items that are ***allowed*** to get removed, while `ItemStack` contains a subset. So yes, it can be pointless, but it can also be perfectly valid.

Comment: Indeed. However, `ItemStack.Remove` is O(1), even if `ItemStack` doesn't contain the element to remove. Given the naming of `listOfSelectedOldItems`, the `.Contains` call is likely to be O(n). Given these, I can't see a case where following your answer is quicker than just calling `ItemStack.Remove` for every item in `listOfSelectedOldItems`.

Comment: Ahh. ok. didn't think of it in that way. That's perfectly true if having the fastest code is most important.